# How to append a element that have more childs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to append a table but i do it the wrong way.. I have this:

```
$("#times").append('<table id="departure_' + i + '" width="50%">    <tbody><tr><td>' + data.times[i].destination.name + '</td><td id="appendLate' + i + '">' + time + '</td><td>' + data.times[i].track + '</td><td>' + data.times[i].train_type + '</td><td>' + data.times[i].company + '</td></tr></tbody></table>');
```

this masive line make no table but alot of tabels.. hard to style.
how can i fix this?

see in action here: http://codepen.io/shiva112/pen/JGXoVJ?editors=001

Comment: if you down-vote this. Please, at lease leave a comment why you do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending the whole table in a for statement. You should do something like this

```
// Select or create a table here
var table = $("#my-target-table");
var tableContent = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.times.length; ++i) {
  tableContent += '<tr><td>' + data.times[i].destination.name + '</td><td id="appendLate' + i + '">' + time + '</td><td>' + data.times[i].track + '</td><td>' + data.times[i].train_type + '</td><td>' + data.times[i].company + '</td></tr>'
}

table.find('tbody').html(tableContent);
```

Comment: You forgot to comment a "}'' check it out here:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLGjMd?editors=001